# Removing duplicates in a string using grep

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, grep

i have a log file containing modules and queries in this order:

```
com.ab
com.ab
com.ac
com.ad
com.ab
com.ac
com.ad
```

hence i used the following grep command to remove duplicates :

```
grep -m1 'com.a' filename
```

but it was not giving the correct output as i wanted the output to be such that it removes duplicates and also finds distinct pattern:

```
com.ab
com.ac
com.ad
```

how do i achieve the above output using grep

Comment: `awk '!seen[$0]++' file.txt`

Comment: `sort -u filename`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
grep -F 'com.a' file | sort -u
awk '/com\.a/' file | sort -u
awk 'index($0, "com.a")' file | sort -u
awk 'index($0, "com.a") && !seen[$0]++' file
```

Here, the `grep -F 'com.a' file` searches for a fixed `com.a` text in `file` (`awk` searches for a `com.a` substring on every line using the `com\.a` regex, and `index($0, "com.a")` version searches for `com.a` as literal string) and `sort -u` sorts the output and returns unique values.

The `awk 'index($0, "com.a") && !seen[$0]++' file` solution is probably the best, everything is done in a single `awk`, see the [online demo](https://ideone.com/b6L54F). Only those unique lines are printed that contain a `com.a` substring.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you my favourite:

```
| sort | uniq
```

When you put this after some list (like `cat filename`), you only get the distinct values, the duplicates get removed.

The reason I'm using this, is the flexibility: you can easily add a criterion to the sorting, like `sort -k3 -n`, and in case needed, you can count the amount of duplicates, adding `-c` at the `uniq` command, which might all be combined into `| sort -k3 -n | uniq -c`, which first orders your list, based on the third column, the sorting is done in a numerical way and afterwards, the duplicates get shown and counted.